# Signing by team development of VSTO add-in for PowerPoint in C#

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, clickonce, add-in, signing

I and another guy are developing an add-in project for PowerPoint using C# and VSTO. Our project is being kept in a repository and every time when one of us gets a newest version from the repository, updated by another one, he gets a compiler problem with signing. Up to now, we solved this compiler problem by generating a test certificate on the corresponding machine **every time** after updating from repository.

My question is: Is it possible to avoid somehow this every-time generating of a test certificate after taking the solution, compilable on other machine, from the repository in order to have it compilable on both machines?

We tried everything:

1. We used the same .pfx file for both of our PC's (i.e. we sent this file to the repository).
2. We tried to uncheck the checkbox "Sign the ClickOnce Manifest" in the Properties window of the Solution and to remove the .pfx file at all.
3. We tried to use our own .pfx files with putting them into the ignore list.

But there was no result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. The solution is probably found. The steps are the following:

1. One developer should generate a new .pfx file defining the password. As a result, he can already develop the add-in correctly, on his machine; but other developer still can **not**, on their machines.
2. Using the same tab of the project's "Properties" window, this developer has to select **the same** .pfx file with the "Select from File..." button, giving the password.
3. The .pfx file should be sent to the repository (i.e. one shouldn't include it into the ignore list). As a result, other developers will not be required to generate anytime other .pfx files anymore.

We are ready!

The "magic" is that knowing the password by all developers is crucial. When the .pfx file is added to the project as it is described in the item 2, it means that all developers know the password.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar scenario and we are doing the following:

1. 'Sign the ClickOnce manifest' is signed with a locally generated .pfx key that is checked into the repository.
2. The assembly is signed with a strong name key.
3. On the build server the manifest is re-signed using the company's digital certificate for deployment using the instructions provided in this article - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2009/04/29/signing-and-re-signing-manifests-in-clickonce.aspx